# Python Comparing lists averages sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, average

I am currently working on a python problem that involves taking a list consisting of 2 sublists of numbers and an identifier, for a total of three things. The procedure name is compareTeams(lstTeams), and is meant to be used to calculate the average winning percentage of teams over a number of seasons. The first list is the games won, the second list is the games lost. The procedure in question takes a list of these lists and tries to find the highest average by adding up the games won over the total games then diving that out by the length of the list. Both lists have the same size. It then sorts the averages in order from greatest to least as pairs of lists, with the identifier tagging along as the first element in each list. To provide an example:

```
teamA = [[6, 4, 8, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0, 2, 4], 'A'] avg winning percentage = 0.56
```

*(in case my explanation is poor and hard to follow, for teamA, the percentage is calculated as (6/9 + 4/10 + 8/8 + 5/7 + 0/4) / 5)*

```
teamB = [[3, 6, 8, 2, 4], [3, 6, 8, 2, 4], 'B'] avg winning percentage = 0.50
teamC = [[3, 6, 8, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'C'] avg winning percentage = 1

compareTeams([teamA, teamB, teamC]) gives [['C', 1],['A', 0.56],['B', 0.50]]
```

I have given this problem a good amount of thought, but am new to python, so I am unsure if I am calling everything correctly. The interpreter I am using does not even display my procedure when I run it, which leads me to believe that I may be doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
def compareTeams(lstTeams):
  a = 0
  x = 0
  lst = []
  y = lstTeams[a]
  for a in range(0, len(y)):
    x = x + ((float(y[0][0]) / (y[1][0])) / len(y[0]))
    a = a + 1
    lst.append(x)
  return lst.reverse(lst.sort())
```

Is this correct? Am I doing anything wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am using python 2.7 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` here:

```
def compare_team(teams):
   lis = []
   for team in teams:
       #zip fetches items from the same index one by one from the lists passed to it
       avg = sum( (x*1.0)/(x+y) for x,y in zip(team[0],team[1]))/ len(team[0])
       lis.append([team[-1],avg])

   lis.sort(key = lambda x:x[1],reverse = True) #reverse sort based on the second item
   return lis



>>> compare_team(([teamA, teamB, teamC]))
[['C', 1.0], ['A', 0.5561904761904761], ['B', 0.5]]
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you, Ashwini. Although, if I may ask, what do key and zip do here exactly? I've never seen those keywords before.

Comment: @Gabe See some zip's examples on [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).
`key` is used to tell the sorting function that what value is to be used to compare the items, So here I used second item from each list for comparison. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Ah, that makes sense with what's going on then. Much appreciated.